# How to properly request a server on loop?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of cities. A pretty big array. For every city in the array I need to make 2 requests to my server - 1 request to get the current weather for the city, and another 1 to get today news. For each of those 2 requests there is a special API endpoint.
How do I get all the neccessary information properly? I mean:

1. don't make too many requests per second
2. the final result should store information in the same order as the cities are stored in the array
3. if some of the requests are failed, don't stop requesting for the other cities (not like in Promise.all)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) and then use a timeout to wait for a certain period of time and redo the same. Make sure to use also a request timeout (so when a server is not responding for a long time, you may want to abort).

Here is an example:

```
const myFunc = async () => {
  await Promise.allSettled([ ... ]);
  setTimeout(myFunc, 1000);
};
```